# Why do the following netstat, ps, and auth.log have such output?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, networking, authorization

I seem to be getting a lot of different connections (ssh) on this Ubuntu server I am sshed into. Are these just brute force attempts?

When running `netstat -tnpa | grep 'ESTABLISHED.*sshd'` why do I get at end of each line "root@p" and "[accep" respectively?

Furthermore, when running `grep sshd.\*Failed /var/log/auth.log | tail -20` I seem to get a lot of different "invalid users". Why is that so?
Lastly, `ps auxwww | grep sshd:` outputs two "[accepted]". Why is that so?

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Update:

Another interesting thing happened now. I ran  `netstat -tnpa | grep 'ESTABLISHED.*sshd'` again and an IP in the form "103.100.xxxx" from Hong Kong apparently was listed. I had then run  `cat /var/log/auth.log | tail -100` and  gotten the following

```
Feb 16 17:58:25 838396123831 sshd[227710]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.100.210.xxx  user=root
Feb 16 17:58:26 838396123831 sshd[227708]: Received disconnect from 103.136.xxxxp ort 33268:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Feb 16 17:58:26 838396123831 sshd[227708]: Disconnected from invalid user hero 103.136.xxxx port 33268 [preauth]
Feb 16 17:58:27 838396123831 sshd[227710]: Failed password for root from 103.100.xxxx port 40810 ssh2
Feb 16 17:58:27 838396123831 sshd[227710]: Received disconnect from 103.100.xxxx port 40810:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Feb 16 17:58:27 838396123831 sshd[227710]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 103.100.xxxx port 40810 [preauth]
```

Then I ran `grep sshd.\*Failed /var/log/auth.log | tail -20` and spotted `Feb 16 18:00:42 838396123831 sshd[227760]: Failed password for invalid user ircbot from 103.136.xxxxx port 47546 ssh2`

I then run `grep sshd.\*Failed /var/log/auth.log | tail -100` and see

```
Feb 16 17:53:24 838396123831 sshd[227596]: Failed password for root from 103.136.xxxx port 33470 ssh2
Feb 16 17:55:57 838396123831 sshd[227652]: Failed password for root from 103.136.xxxxx port 47406 ssh2

Feb 16 17:58:24 838396123831 sshd[227708]: Failed password for invalid user hero from 103.136.xxxxx port 33268 ssh2
Feb 16 18:00:42 838396123831 sshd[227760]: Failed password for invalid user ircbot from 103.136.xxxxx port 47546 ssh2
```

What does this mean? What is happening? Was or is any other person managed to log in to the server via ssh? "Last" command does not list any other Ip addresses except mine so...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My server is constantly being attacked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184813/my-server-is-constantly-being-attacked)

Comment: Thanks so much. That is what I suspected. One last question. If no one except me has managed to successfully ssh into my server why does ``netstat -tnpa | grep 'ESTABLISHED.*sshd'`` print more? What does the "root@p" and "[accep" for example mean? @Kusalananda

Comment: The root user is the one running `sshd`, always, and it forks off a `sshd` for each established connection. If you have logged into this machine using SSH, then this is what I would expect to see. But I would leave it to some other Linux person to say for certiain that it looks ok (I'm not a Linux user, I run OpenBSD).

Comment: Oh ok. If a user is running "ssh root@ipaddressofmyserver" then even if they fail to authenticate and log in, when they run that ssh command will ``netstat -tnpa | grep 'ESTABLISHED.*sshd'`` show them?

Comment: And thanks for explaining "root@p" but what is "[accep" ? @Kusalananda

Comment: I _believe_ so, yes. Someone else may have to back me up on that. The `p` is actually `pts/0`, see your 2nd screenshot. You can also see the full string `[accepted]` there.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Why "root@pts/0" and "[accept]" ? What is each for? How are they different?

Comment: It's just a way that `sshd` lets you know what each instance of itself is for. The `pts/0` one is the one that accepts incoming connections.  The `[accepted]` is a `sshd` that has accepted an incoming connection (started for this purpose by the first one). Can't say much more than that I'm afraid. I'm sure there are other answers on this site that mentions these.

Comment: "started for this purpose by the first one" -  What first one are you referring to?

Comment: The one marked `pts/0`, which is listening for connections.

Comment: "pts" is a pseudo terminal right? How is it listening for connections?

Comment: Nothing of this is in your actual question.

Comment: Read `man journalctl`, `sudo journalctl -b 0 $(type -p sshd)`

Comment: I read the manpage and understand it. How is ``sudo journalctl -b 0 $(type -p sshd) `` helpful though? What am I seeing? @waltinator   I mean which question of mine are you answering by this

Comment: Nothing of this is in your actual question.  -- Yes, I know. This question came up in my head when you explained the full form of "root@p" and "[accep" , So how is pts/0 listening for connections if it is just a pseudo terminal?  @Kusalananda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The netstat command is giving you what is happening within your Linux system.
Firstly, your Linux server is directly exposed to the internet. Attackers will always try to guess the username and password to SSH service.

The most secure way to SSH into a Linux server is through VPN. This means that the SSH server will sit behind the VPN gateway and only accessible through VPN. But VPN is not always possible.

The easiest way to lock-down your SSH server is by editing the `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf` file. In this file, [whitelist the users](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-limit-what-users-can-log-onto-system-via-ssh/) allowed to SSH. Source IP can be trick since some users are mobile, or their ISP is using dynamic IP

A better dynamic way to protect SSH is by installing [fail2ban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban)

Comment: Thanks. So the "ESTABLISHED" in the netstat command output does not mean another person has successfully sshd but that it was an in progress attempt?

Comment: When anyone attempts to SSH into a server, a TCP three-way handshake must be completed first. The client will first send a TCP SYNC packet, server will respond with a TCP SYNC/ACK, then client will respond with a TCP ACK, and then a TCP connection is established. At this stage, no username or password have been sent yet. At this stage, netstat command will show that the connection is "ESTABLISHED". In other words, a connection must be "ESTABLISHED" before a legitimate user logs in or a rogue user attempts to brute-force.